# Java: Map.of<"k1", "v1"> vs Collections.singletonMap("k1", "v1")

Tags: java

Are there any differences between `Map.of("key", "value")` and `Collections.singletonMap("key", "value")`?

Are there any practices on which one is to be preferred over another if I just need to store one mapping for Java 9 and above?

Comment: For example, `Collections.singletonMap` works with a null key. `Map.of` throws a NPE.

Comment: In fact, `Map.of(...)` required both the key and the value to be non-null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Map.of

`Map.of` can only be used in Java 9 and above. It can be used to store 0 to 10 key-value pairs. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-- and following. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable:

> The Map.of() and Map.ofEntries() static factory methods provide a
> convenient way to create immutable maps. The Map instances created by
> these methods have the following characteristics:
>
> - They are structurally immutable. Keys and values cannot be added, removed, or updated. Calling any mutator method will always cause
>   UnsupportedOperationException to be thrown. However, if the contained
>   keys or values are themselves mutable, this may cause the Map to
>   behave inconsistently or its contents to appear to change.
> - They disallow null keys and values. Attempts to create them with null keys or values result in NullPointerException.
> - They are serializable if all keys and values are serializable.
> - They reject duplicate keys at creation time. Duplicate keys passed to a static factory method result in IllegalArgumentException.
> - The iteration order of mappings is unspecified and is subject to change.
>   They are value-based. Callers should make no assumptions about the identity of the returned instances. Factories are free to create new
>   instances or reuse existing ones. Therefore, identity-sensitive
>   operations on these instances (reference equality (==), identity hash
>   code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.
>   They are serialized as specified on the Serialized Form page.

Similarily, there is `List.of` and `Set.of`.

### Collections.singletonMap

`Collections.singletonMap` is available since Java 1.3. It can only be used to store one key-value pair. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-.

In general, singletons always contain exactly one value. A singleton class is one that has exactly one instance. A singleton map has exactly one mapping, a singleton list has exactly one element and so on.

Comment: I was not very clear in my question. Updated it now. If I have just one mapping are there any preferences for using `Map.of("k", "v")` over `Collections.singletonMap("k", "v")` or vice versa for java 9 and above?

Comment: One is shorter :-) Otherwise there is no difference in your case, although implementations could differ in theory but that would depend on which JDK you choose but I don't think there is any practical difference for your specific use case.

Comment: There is one important difference between `Collections.singletonMap()` and `Map.of()`: `Collections.singletonMap()` accepts `null` for both key and value, `Map.of()` doesn't accept nulls.

Comment: @ThomasKläger: Yes, but @tuk was asking specifically about `Map.of("k", "v")`.